# How to export all the reports to excel in single workbook from one folder on the report server in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I had the below requirement.

I created the reports for example in SSRS

Sales Report A,
Sales Report B and 
Sales Report C

and deployed the reports to the folder 'SALES OPERATIONS' on the report server.

Instead of running each report i want  to run all the  3 reports in the 'SALES OPERATIONS' folder at once and export all the 3  reports in same excel workbook.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to make service for that.

Comment: Can you please let me know what service i need to make

Answer (score 0):

Is below what you need?

- Create a master report and drop several rectangles onto it.
- Within each rectangle, embed your report A/B/C as subreport.
- Open property window of rectangle and add a page break for each rectangle.
- When export the report to Excel, each report should be on different tabs.

Comment: Thanks  for your reply. My requirement is after deploying the reports i want to run all the reports in the particular folder and export it to the same excel workbook